# A function like: ng-click="alert('Clicked')"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

For a mockup I need a simple mechanism like

```
ng-click="alert('Clicked')"
```

but the code above is not working, can someone help me? I don't want to touch the Controller..

Comment: this isn't how `ng-click` works.  however, if all you need is a simple javascript alert, why are you using `ng-click` instead of `onclick`?

Comment: we want to show an angular mockup, that's the only reason. I've added a controller function but I let the question here, maybe one day angular team would implement such of simple possibilities via ng-click..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `ng-click` works only within your `$scope`. So you would only be able to call functions, defined in your `$scope` itself. To use alert, you may try accessing the `window` element, just by using `window.alert('Clicked')`.

**EIDT:** Thanks to Ibrahim. I forgot. You shouldn't be able to use `window.alert`, as far as you won't define:

```
$scope.alert = window.alert;
```

In this case, using `alert('Clicked')` in your `ng-clicked` directive should work. But at the end, this method would not solve your problem of not touching your controller.

Comment: it wont work either, because angular will look for "$scope.window.alert" function, you can write a simple directive for that need which takes string and alerts it.

Comment: of course if you mean `ng-click="window.alert('clicked')"`, if you mean to write function in scope, then you do not necesarilly use window.alert, just alert will work too.

Comment: ok, if I need the scope, I use direct `href="javascript:...` :/

Comment: Thank you both, but: I need a solution without touching the Controller's $scope.

Answer (score 7):

**Refer to previous answer**, ng-click = "alert('Hello World!')" will work only if $scope points to window.alert i.e

```
$scope.alert = window.alert;
```

**But even it creates eval problem so correct syntax must be:**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-click = "alert('Hello World!')">Click me</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.alert = function(arg){
    alert(arg);
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this one did

Comment: @Joe,@Neeraj, where you putting the definition ? "Controller" you mean inside .ts file ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
onclick="alert('Clicked')"
```

for debugging purposes

Answer (score 2):

As Neeraj mentioned, the accepted answer does not work. Add something like this to your controller to avoid an `Illegal Invocation` error:

```
$scope.alert = alert.bind(window);
```

Comment: I have to use this instead of the accepted answer while I am using Ionic 1.3 which is dependent on AngularJS 1.5