# How can I replace link hrefs with ngClicks in dynamically generated HTML within AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm consuming dynamically generated HTML from an API which may contain hyperlinks, and I'm wanting to replace the hrefs within them with ngClicks.  The following directive appears to modify the HTML as intended when I check it in a DOM inspector, but clicking it does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
app.directive('replaceLinks', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function(scope) {
                return scope.$eval(attrs.replaceLinks);
            }, function(value) {

                element.html(value);

                angular.forEach(element.contents().find("a"), function(link) {
                    link.removeAttribute("href");
                    link.removeAttribute("target");
                    link.setAttribute("ng-click", "alert('test')");
                });

                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Please show an example of how this directive is used and explain the problem that occurs. It would be wiser to attach click handlers directly instead of adding ng-click directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of removing the `href` please set it to `blank` (this will preserve the link css), also the `ng-click` calling the alert can be done by calling the `alert('test')` inside of a scope method, why the alert didn't fire, is explained in this [`SO Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899173/a-function-like-ng-click-alertclicked), please refer the below sample code!

```js
// <body ng-app='myApp' binds to the app being created below.
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('replaceLinks', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.forEach(element.find("a"), function(link) {
        link.setAttribute("href", "");
        link.removeAttribute("target");
        link.setAttribute("ng-click", "scopeAlert('test')");
      });
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);


    }
  };
}]);
// Register MyController object to this app
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);

// We define a simple controller constructor.
function MyController($scope) {
  // On controller load, assign 'World' to the "name" model
  // in <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.scopeAlert = function(name) {
    window.alert(name);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div replace-links>
    <a href="#">test 1</a>
    <a href="#">test 2</a>
    <a href="#">test 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the scope restriction was exactly what I was missing.